# Pandas default arguments

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As part of my day to day work, I need to read in csv files, write csv files, merge dataframes, and rename columns at least 10s of times a day.

I **always** have to change the default pandas arguments for these to the following:

- `df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', dtype='str')`
- `df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False)`
- `df = df.merge(df, how='left')`
- `df = df.rename(columns={'a':'b'}, errors='raise')`

It's one of those things that I keep wanting to avoid, but is small enough to not invest a huge amount of time fixing.

I've done some digging and come to a possible solution:

```
from functools import partial

pd.read_csv = partial(pd.read_csv, dtype='str')
```

I can put this at the top of any code I'm writing and no longer need to specify the dtype.

The problems with this are:

1. It only works for pd, not pd.DataFrame functions.
2. I need to run this command in every new python session, I'll often open a python session to do some ad hoc data processing.

Is there any way to change the default arguments at an environment level?

I do realise this isn't best practise, but it could save me from RSI, and I **always** want these to be the default arguments

Comment: Why don't you just define a functions that call the pandas functions with the arguments you want?

Comment: Wouldn't I have to define these functions every time I start a new python session?

Comment: If this is just for interactive python shells, you can use the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable to hold the path to a script that gets imported automatically.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! I'm using IPython within Spyder generally for this. Is there any way to run PYTHONSTARTUP before running any python script?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Check its documentation.

Comment: Always passing `index=False` will lead to issues when the index is meaningful, eg in a group by or cross tab. I would recommend strongly against hiding something important like that: it will make it difficult to debug such issues.

Comment: Thanks will do @Barmar.

Comment: Thanks @ifly6, I realise it's not best practise, but as I said, I always read in with index=False, there are no exceptions to this rule